# rails update field based on find in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model (has_many contacts) and a Contact model (belongs_to user). To send invites, I need to know if a user's contacts already exist in User table and update a status field in Contacts. My common field is phone number.

So oversimplifying I have:

User: id, phone

Contact: id, name, phone, status, user_id

How can I set status to "registered" for a user's contacts in an efficient manner?

I currently have this iteration, which works, but there has to be a better way:

```
all_contacts = Contact.where(user_id: user).where.not(phone: nil)
all_contacts.each do |contact|
  a = User.find_by(phone: contact.phone)
  if a
    contact.status = 'registered'
    contact.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
contacts = Contact.joins(:user).where("users.phone=contacts.phone and contacts.phone not NULL")
contact_ids = fetch ids from contacts array
Contact.update(your_array_of_ids, status: "registered")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. In this way, there is no iteration required. The join and where clause handles finding the contacts registered as users. Databases are very efficient at this sort of thing, using indexes and memory as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update status of User to "registered" only if they have a phone number, then you could store their ids in an array(using `where` for example , and then you could use the [update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) method like this:

```
User.update(your_array_of_ids, status: "registered")
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want to update the status of each Contact if the phone number of the contact exists in the User table